# Angular 7 Library - Circular Dependency Detected (Directive, Service, Module)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-directive, circular-dependency

i created a new Angular 7 project with a library. That lib contains a directive, a service and a module (directive get's the service injected and the service a injectionToken which is exported in the module).
I get this warnings while compiling:

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected: projects\auth\src\lib\auth.module.ts ->
>   projects\auth\src\lib\login-form-ref.directive.ts ->
>   projects\auth\src\lib\auth.service.ts ->
>   projects\auth\src\lib\auth.module.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   projects\auth\src\lib\auth.service.ts ->
>   projects\auth\src\lib\auth.module.ts ->
>   projects\auth\src\lib\login-form-ref.directive.ts ->
>   projects\auth\src\lib\auth.service.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   projects\auth\src\lib\login-form-ref.directive.ts ->
>   projects\auth\src\lib\auth.service.ts ->
>   projects\auth\src\lib\auth.module.ts ->
>   projects\auth\src\lib\login-form-ref.directive.ts

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Token } from './models/token';
import { OAuthClient } from './models/oAuthClient';
import { OAUTH_CONFIGURATION } from './auth.module';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  expectedHttpResponse = 200;

  constructor(
    @Inject(OAUTH_CONFIGURATION) private readonly oAuthClient: OAuthClient
    , private readonly http: HttpClient
  ) { }
...
```

auth.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginFormRefDirective } from './login-form-ref.directive';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { OAuthClient } from './models/oAuthClient';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

export const OAUTH_CONFIGURATION = new InjectionToken<OAuthClient>('OAUTH_CONFIGURATION');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginFormRefDirective],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [LoginFormRefDirective]
})
export class AuthModule {
  static forRoot(oAuthClientConfig: OAuthClient) {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: OAUTH_CONFIGURATION, useValue: oAuthClientConfig }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

login-form-ref.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Self, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';
import { Token } from './models/token';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[loginFormRef]'
})
export class LoginFormRefDirective {
  @Input() storeTokenMethod: (token) => void;

  constructor(
    @Self() private readonly formGroup: FormGroupDirective
    , private readonly _authService: AuthService
  ) { }
...
```

I don't know the reason for that problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, there is a circular dependency:

`export const OAUTH_CONFIGURATION = new InjectionToken<OAuthClient>('OAUTH_CONFIGURATION');`

where `OAUTH_CONFIGURATION` is exported from `auth.module`, which is imported into `auth.service`, and `auth.service` is imported into `auth.module` and the directive.

Try placing the Injection token in a new file, and importing it in `auth.service` and `auth.module`.

token.ts:

```
export const OAUTH_CONFIGURATION = new InjectionToken<OAuthClient>('OAUTH_CONFIGURATION');
```

other files:

```
import { OAUTH_CONFIGURATION } from './token';
```

Comment: oh damn..that's a shame..
Thanks for your solution, it worked for me!

Comment: Glad to hear it :) please accept my answer if it worked!